# ffmpeg prores alpha channel not present when colormatrix and colorspace operations are performed

Tags: ffmpeg, prores, colorspace, alpha

So I've figured out how to convert images to prores with no colorspace shifts using either:

`-vf colormatrix=bt601:bt709` filter for 8bit material

and

`-vf colorspace=all=bt709:range=pc:format=yuv444p10:iall='bt601-6-625':irange=pc` filter for 8bit or 10bit material.

However, whenever I use `colormatrix` or `colorspace` filters the output file contains no alpha channel.  As soon as I remove these filters the alpha channel is present but now I've got a color shift.

```
#this generates no alpha
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 24.0 -i tif_w_alpha.%3d.tif -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 5 -pix_fmt yuva444p10le -vf colorspace=all=bt709:range=pc:format=yuv444p10:iall='bt601-6-625':irange=pc -alpha_bits 16 this_has_no_alpha_channel.mov

#this has alpha but also a color shift
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 24.0 -i tif_w_alpha.%3d.tif -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 5 -pix_fmt yuva444p10le -alpha_bits 16 this_has_alpha.mov
```

This behavior is the same in both -profile:v 4 and 5 which are the only 2 that support alpha.  How can I get the color filter to work without losing the alpha channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colorspace and colormatrix filters don't handle alpha pixel formats, so those get stripped off. The workaround is to extract the alpha and then reattach it.

`ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 24.0 -i tif_w_alpha.%3d.tif -filter_complex "[0]colorspace=all=bt709:range=pc:format=yuv444p10:iall='bt601-6-625':irange=pc[main];[0]alphaextract,format=gray10le[alpha];[main][alpha]alphamerge" -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 5 -pix_fmt yuva444p10le -alpha_bits 16 this_has_no_alpha_channel.mov`

BTW, The Quicktime specification doesn't accommodate output range `pc`. Consumers should expect to treat range as always `tv`. If your software allows to override that, nice, but other software may not.

Comment: Thanks.  Not using quicktime for this data.  The software I will be using handles it fine.  Not sure you can even do anything with alpha inside the quicktime app.

Comment: Got it working, thanks!

Comment: Why did you change the filter ordering?

Comment: The ordering you originally posted caused my encode to hang on the last frame.  Killing the process just produced a corrupt file.  Switching the ordering fixed it and produced a correct color and alpha prores file.

Comment: That should not make a difference. Share full log.

Comment: If you can, share the images.

Comment: Here are full logs of a successful encode and a hung encode as well as a single source frame (they're heavy) on [google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14ilVwS6nT9buUTgszYWd4G3McR7pkRmR)

Comment: Can't reproduce hang here. Version is N-94391. Upgrade and check.

Comment: Thanks for checking.  Not a blocking issue on my end so I'll check and update once I upgrade.